# Кнопка вкл/выкл звука на сайте (jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, веб-программирование

Помогите заставить кнопочку включать и выключать звук. Новичок во всем этом деле, не пойму как заставить работать.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.on').click(function() {
        $('.off').css('display', 'block');
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
    });
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.off').click(function() {
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
        $('.on').css('display', 'block');
    });
});
//еще проблема в том, как управлять самим звуком? я использовал чистый JS, взял его с одного сайта. Может можно все управление переместить сюда?
```

```css
.on {  /*кнопка показывает, что звука нет и при нажатии на неё звук должен пропадать*/
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: red;
  }
.off {  /*кнопка показывает, что звук есть и её не видно, но после предыдущих событий сюда будет записываться display:block При нажатии на неё звук должен появляться*/
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: blue;
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<audio id="myTune" autoplay="true" loop="5" hidden="true">
  <source src="audio/background.mp3">
</audio>
 
<button class="on" onclick="document.getElementById('myTune').play()">ВЫКЛ</button>
<button class="off" onclick="document.getElementById('myTune').pause()">ВКЛ</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
  
$( document ).ready(
function() {
var i=false;
$('.on').click(function() {
 
 if(i){
 
 $('.on').css("backgroundColor", "#0000ff");
 //$('#myTune').play();
 document.getElementById('myTune').play();
     i=false;
$('button.on').html("Выкл");
   }

    else{
  $('.on').css("backgroundColor", "#00ff00");
  i=true;
  document.getElementById('myTune').pause();
  $('button.on').html("Вкл");
        }
   });
});
```

```css
.on {  /*кнопка показывает, что звука нет и при нажатии на неё звук должен пропадать*/
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: red;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="2.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="12313.css">
</head>
<body>



<audio id="myTune" autoplay="true" loop="5" hidden="true">
  <source src="background.mp3">
</audio>
 
<button class="on" >Выкл</button>

</body>
```

вариант с 1 кнопкой.